# Aws connect for spanish(us) IVR

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I  try spanish(us) IVR bot connect with aws connect but when i test in lex it is working fine but when i test in connect number it is not working.

help me to find a way to solve this problem.